API to add multiple labels to an Anaconda package
I am looking for an Anaconda API that will enable me to automate the process of attaching more than one label to a given package.  All of the APIs that I have been able to find treat labels as a simple attribute, rather than recognizing labels as a collection, ex. the commands anaconda label copy/move replace the existing label.  They do not append an additional label.
I know that this is possible from the GUI, when working with packages that I own.  But, I am looking for a way to be able to script this ability.
For a real-world example of a company that is using packages with multiple labels, see ...
In the Anaconda Repository, NVIDIA is using labels to help manage dependencies.  For example, see their install instructions, and version 11.4.43 of cuda-cccl.
